# Import statements not working / I think I broke Python / file structure issues?

Tags: python, file, import, python-import, importerror

[I am new to Python (and programming in general) and will definitely say something stupid in this question.]

I had two python programs. In one of them the import statements were working. And in the other one the import statements were not working.

I suspected this had something to do with the file location of the modules relative to the Python files.

It turned out the program that wasn't working was in a sub folder of the program that was working.

So, as an experiment, I tried moving the venv folder into the sub folder where the other program was, but I ended up canceling that once I discovered that I would need to replace some of the files. (Due to the fact that is already had a venv folder.)

Then, as an experiment, I tried renaming the venv folder to "venv1" just to see if the good program would run. I was not surprised when it didn't.

But then I renamed it back to "venv," and it still wasn't working.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json, requests
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs
import urllib
# .... etc ...
```

output

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

...
...
...

oh, and if I try:

```
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json, requests
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs
import urllib
# .... etc ...
```

Output:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

I tried pip installing them again (my terminal doesn't recognize sudo pip install) and this is what I got

```
PS C:\Users\****\Desktop> pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\****\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (2.27.1)
```

I thought maybe I'd look this one up, but the folder "appdata" doesn't exist on my computer, in that location.

What happened and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The appdata folder should exist in that location.  It is a hidden folder, and by default, Windows won't display hidden files/folders.  You can view it by pressing WIN+R, and then typing "appdata", and clicking "OK".  It should then come up in a file explorer window.

The python packages are installed, but not visible to the scripts.  It sounds like you virtual environment may be incorrectly set up.  If you open a CMD prompt, and then type in `python -m site`, it will show you the locations of your python's system path.  You should see the install locations for the packages, in this case, you'll probably see the following: `C:\\Users\\****\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages`.

Comment: I do see that as well as a few other paths that branch off of the Python310 folder. How do I get my virtual environment set up correctly?